# Complex Pivot like query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having trouble creating a complex `PL SQL` query.

This is the Table - [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1df6f/1)

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD ColumnE
A   Simple1    Para     Red     121
A   Simple1    Para     Blue    122
B   Simple2    Para     Red     123
B   Simple2    Para     Blue    124
C   Simple3    Para     Red     125
C   Simple3    Para     Blue    126
D   Simple4    Para     Red     127
D   Simple4    Para2    Blue    128
D   Simple4    Para3    Green   129
```

And I am expecting an output like this.

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC Red Blue    Green
A   Simple1     Para    121 122     Null
B   Simple2     Para    123 124     Null
C   Simple3     Para    125 126     Null
D   Simple4     Para    127 128     129
D   Simple4     Para2   127 128     129
D   Simple4     Para3   127 128     129
```

Comment: What trouble are you having - what have you tried? Do you really mean PL/SQL, or just Oracle-flavour SQL?

Comment: So where does your output appear? Are you looking for a function that returns a ref cursor? Showing the context you'll be calling this from might help. Your Fiddle doesn't have any PL/SQL or any attempted code. Might also be useful to know which version of Oracle you're using.

Comment: Why do the `Para2` and `Para3` rows keep the values from the `Para` row that they are missing, and vice versa; you want to merge the result based on grouping by ColumnA/ColumnB ? Can you explain your logic some more too please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your requirements, given your desired results, you want to group the red, blue and green columns by `columna` and `columnb`, not including `columnc` in the grouping.

To create the `pivot`, you can use `max` and `case`.  Then you can `join` those results back to the original table using the first 2 columns and `distinct`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       t1.columna, 
       t1.columnb,
       t1.columnc,
       t2.red,
       t2.blue,
       t2.green
FROM Table1 t1
  JOIN (
      SELECT 
          ColumnA, 
          ColumnB, 
          max(case when columnd = 'Red' then columne end) red,
          max(case when columnd = 'Blue' then columne end) blue,
          max(case when columnd = 'Green' then columne end) green
      FROM Table1
      GROUP BY  columna, columnb
    ) t2 ON t1.columna = t2.columna AND t1.columnb = t2.columnb
ORDER BY t1.columna, t1.columnb, t1.columnc
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5c822/7)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use pivot, with analytic functions:

```
select columna,columnb,columnc,max(red) over (partition by columna,columnb), 
max(green) over (partition by columna,columnb), 
max(blue) over (partition by columna,columnb)
from (
select * from t pivot (max(columne) for columnd in ('Red' as red,'Green' as green,
'Blue' as blue) ))
order by 1,2,3
```